# Why positive PV Anomaly moves westwards?

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere-modelling, vorticity

In Jonathan Martin's Book "Mid-Latitude Atmospheric Dynamics" there is a chapter about PV anomalies. As an example, a positive PV anomaly is discussed.[image]
What is the reason, that high PV is advected from the north at the west and low PV is advected from the south at the east of the anomaly in the figure? I cannot follow the argumentation here: Is it because there is generally higher PV in the north near the tropopause?